# Something is changing my negative arguments into 0

Tags: c

Im doing a insertion sort for arguments given into the command line. For some reason, any number I enter that is negative changes to a 0. I can't seem to find where. It works in ascending order as soon as I call my reverse function the negative number turns to 0.

```
void reverse(double *a, int argc)
{
        for (int i = argc-2; i > 0; --i)
        {
                printf("%g\n", a[i]);
        }
}


void sort(double *a, int length)
{
        for (int i = 1; i < length; i++)
        {
                double key = a[i];
                int j = i - 1;

                while (j >= 0 && a[j] > key)
                {
                        swap(&a[j+1],&a[j]);
                        j = j-1;
                }
                a[j+1] = key;
        }
}
void swap(double *x, double *y)
{
        *x = *y;
}


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
        if (is_valid_num(argv[1]) == 1 || strcmp(argv[1], "-r")== 0)
        {
                if (strcmp(argv[1], "-r") == 0)
                {
                        if (reverseDigitChecker(argc, argv) == 1)
                        {
                                double arr[argc -1];
                                for (int i = 1; i < argc; i++)
                                {
                                        double temp = atof(argv[i]);
                                        arr[i-1] = temp;
                                }
                                sort(arr, argc-1);
                                reverse(arr, argc);
                        }
                }
                if (strcmp(argv[1], "-r") != 0)
                {
                        if (digitChecker(argc, argv) == 1)
                        {
                                double arr[argc - 1];
                                for (int i = 1; i < argc; i++)
                                {
                                        double temp = atof(argv[i]);
                                        arr[i-1] = temp;
                                }
                                sort(arr,argc-1);
                                for (int j = 0; j < argc-1; j++)
                                {
                                        printf("%g\n", arr[j]);
                                }
                        }
                }
        }
        else
        {
                printf("%s is an invalid argument.\n", argv[1]);
                usage();
        }
        return 0;
}
```

./sort 5 -10 10 will result in -10 5 10
./sort -r 5 -10 10 will result in 10 5 0 where the 0 used to be -10 and -r means call reverse

Comment: Your `swap()` function doesn't swap, rather it sets the first value equal to the second value.  Is that intended?

Comment: Your swap function is wrong. It assigns the value in `*y` to `*x`, at which point both have the same value. Stepping through the code in a debugger will help you find these sorts of coding errors pretty easily. If you don't know how to use a debugger, now is the perfect time to learn - the debugger is the most powerful tool a programmer has available.

Comment: @JeremyFriesner Hmm is that why it seems to output the correct answer when I don't call the reverse function? because its not a permenant swap. How could I fix the swap function?

Comment: `void swap(double *x, double *y)
{
 double tmp = *x; *x = *y;  *y = tmp;
}`

Comment: The problem is that when there is a `-r` your loop needs to start at index 2 and not index 1 because the actual `-r` is at index 1 and when converted to a double with atof it returns 0.  Here is a version that works: https://onlinegdb.com/ojRDcUYJJ